# case end / self-join postres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to process data within the same table.

Input:
**Table**

```
id sort value   
1   1     1   
2   1     8    
3   2     0    
4   1     2
```

What I want to achieve is obtain for each id, the first encountered value for all value equal to its sort, and this ordered by id.

Output

**Table**

```
id sort value new  
1   1     1    1    
2   1     8    1      
3   2     0    0      
4   1     2    1
```

I tried to self join the table, but I constantly get relation not found. I tried with a case statement but I don't see how can I connect to the same table, I get the same error, relation not found.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of SQL is that many requirements (yours included) can be verbosely described in very similar way they are finally coded:

```
with t(id, sort, value   ) as (values
(1,   1,     1),   
(2,   1,     8),    
(3,   2,     0),    
(4,   1,     2)
)
select t.*
     , first_value(value) over (partition by sort order by id) as "new"
from t
order by id
```

| id | sort | value | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UBQu9pla)

Comment: Will last_value(value) over (partition by sort order by id) as "new2" also give the last value ? because when i attempt to do this, I basically get the value back, and not the last one

Comment: This is because window is by default defined as `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` hence the `last_value` of such a window is the value at current row. With `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` you get last value you want - see this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/AYJXApCF .

Comment: If I want to select multiple value over the same partition, what is the most efficient way to write it? For example I want the first/last/average/min/max. Currently I have each time : first(value) over (...), last(value) over (...), and so on, but I am wondering if there is a better way for it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, look at the `window` clause at the end of [this documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).